# How to extract an image per minute from video with a predefined starting frame in cv2 VideoCapture

Tags: image, extract, frame, opencv, python

I would like to extract one image per minute from an mp4 video recording and I have a code for that already, however, I also would like to add a starting frame from where the extraction should start and either set an ending frame or the number of images that should be extracted.
This is because I would like to avoid trimming the videos as it takes a very long time.

My existing code to extract the images is the following:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(r'C:my_folder/my_video.mp4') 
i = 1
while (cap.isOpened()):
ret, frame = cap.read()

if ret == False:
    break
if i % 1800 == 0: 
    cv2.imwrite(r'C:/my_folder/pictures/' + str(i) + '.jpg', frame) 
                                                                                                    
i += 1
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Let's say I would like to start the extraction from frame 2700 and from that every 1800th frame until I have 30 frames.

Is there a way to do this? Every help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `if` condition to the following:

```
if i > 2700 and i % 1800 == 0:
```

Comment: Hello, some exaplanation for this answer will be welcome.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: What I did with the code of @user3805577 is to insert it into my main code as suggested and I also added ` if i > 18000: break ` after the ` cv2.imwrite ` line to stop the extraction at the 18000th frame. In this way, the first frame that corresponds to the 1800 loop - counting from frame 0 - after the 2700th frame will be extracted first, the 3600th in this case. And the last one will be the 18000th.